# Analog of TableLayoutPanel in Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

In .NET if I want to create window with two panels on the sides, I can add the [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) on the window, and specify three columns: fixed sized, auto-sized, and fixed-sized again. Both panels will **save their size in a case of window resizing.**

How can I do this with Swing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a simple `BorderLayout` will do the trick. It allows to specify up to 5 panels (PAGE_START, PAGE_END, LINE_START, CENTER, LINE_END) but you will only need the last 3 ones. All extra available size goes to the CENTER area, meaning the size of your side panels remains constant.

Just for reference: the [Visual guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is always a good starting point if you are looking for a `LayoutManager` with certain properties

Answer (score 2):

There is a lib called Mig-Layout (http://www.miglayout.com/) that can do this. You probably also could do this using internal Layouts, but I actually always use Mig-Layout even though the lib is pretty big.